# Pandas groupby and apply custom function comparing two columns to alter another column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that I need to group by `id` then within these groups, compare column `A` and `B` to alter column `C`.

Here is my code:

```
def alter_C(row):
    if row['A'].shift(1) == row['B'] :
           row['C'] = 'new_value'
           return row

df = df.groupby(id).apply(alter_C)
```

I get the error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Can you help please?

Comment: you do not need groupby here, check np.where

Comment: Edited my post, I need a group by because I'm comparing consecutive rows within these groups, thanks for your response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `apply` after a `groupby`, the input to the function will be a dataframe. So `row` in your function is not a single row. You can check this by running `type(row)` which will give you `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`.

We therefore need to treat `row` as a dataframe when changing the `C` column. It can be done as follows:

```
def alter_C(df_group):
    df_group.loc[df_group['A'].shift(1) == df_group['B'], 'C'] = 'new_value'
    return df_group

df = df.groupby('id').apply(alter_C)
```